# Bicep deployment failes: configuration scope InGuestPatch aren't supported

Tags: azure-bicep

We are in the process of deploying Azure Update Manager using Bicep. The bicep so far consists of two parts.

1. maintenanceConfiguration - Succesvol
2. maintenanceConfigurationAssignement - Failed

The first part is to create the maintenance configuration itself, which works.

The second is to create the assignment and assign it to the maintenanceConfiguration.

I looked at it with several engineers and whatever we do we get the following error.

Error message:

> New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: C:\Scripts\maintenance
> Configuration\powershell\deploy-resource.ps1:10:1
> Line |
> 10 |  New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
> |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> | 11:19:09 - The deployment 'DeployLocalTemplate' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s). Status Message: Patch configuration is only applicable for InGuestPatch scope (Code:)  CorrelationId: 5754e928-5fc3-4f2a-95ff-e40f9f7bac4c

The bicep section `maintenanceConfiguration` is exported out of Azure, and the parameters and `maintenanceConfigurationAssignment` are added afterward.

```
param maintenanceConfigurationsName string = 'upd-group3-dtap-06am-pt-02-2024'

@description('Default location')
param location string = 'westeurope'

@description('Defined rebootSetting')
@allowed([
  'IfRequired'
  'Always'
  'Never'
])
param rebootSetting string = 'Always'

param resourceId string = newGuid()

param targetTag object = {
  InSpark_ManagedUpdateGroup: 'infr-upd-group2' 
}

param subscription string = 'f45372af-b935-4a3d-9ec3-2e4884fb186f'

resource maintenanceConfiguration 'microsoft.maintenance/maintenanceconfigurations@2023-09-01-preview' = {
  name: maintenanceConfigurationsName
  location: location
  tags: {
    inSpark_InfrastructureManagedBy: 'xxxxxx'
  }
  properties: {
    extensionProperties: {
      InGuestpatchMode: 'User'
    }
    maintenanceScope: 'InGuestPatch'
    maintenanceWindow: {
      startDateTime: '2024-01-23 06:00'
      expirationDateTime: '2024-01-25 06:00'
      duration: '03:55'
      timeZone: 'W. Europe Standard Time'
      recurEvery: 'Day'
    }
    visibility: 'Custom'
    installPatches: {
      rebootSetting: rebootSetting
      windowsParameters: {
        classificationsToInclude: [
          'Critical'
          'Security'
        ]
      }
      linuxParameters: {
        classificationsToInclude: [
          'Critical'
          'Security'
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

resource maintenanceConfigurationAssignment 'Microsoft.Maintenance/configurationAssignments@2023-04-01' = {
  name: 'assignment'
  location: location
  scope: maintenanceConfiguration
  properties: {
    filter: {
      tagSettings: {
        filterOperator: 'Any'
        tags: targetTag 
      }
    }
    maintenanceConfigurationId: maintenanceConfiguration.id
    resourceId: resourceId
  }
}
```

We tried to alter the extensionProperties and the maintenancescope but in the end we only get the first part working using User and InGuestPatch, this was also the parameters using the export function in azure based of on existing maintenanceConfiguration.

Below is the result of the latest test.

```
PS C:\Scripts\maintenance Configuration> . 'C:\Scripts\maintenance Configuration\powershell\deploy-resource.ps1'
VERBOSE: Using Bicep v0.24.24
WARNING: C:\Scripts\maintenance Configuration\bicep\main.bicep(20,7) : Warning no-unused-params: Parameter "subscription" is declared but never used. [https://aka.ms/bicep/linter/no-unused-params]
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Creating Deployment" on target "infr-automation-weu-rg".
VERBOSE: 11:19:58 - Template is valid.
VERBOSE: 11:19:59 - Create template deployment 'DeployLocalTemplate'
VERBOSE: 11:19:59 - Checking deployment status in 5 seconds
VERBOSE: 11:20:04 - Resource Microsoft.Maintenance/maintenanceConfigurations 'upd-group3-dtap-06am-pt-02-2024' provisioning status is succeeded
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: C:\Scripts\maintenance Configuration\powershell\deploy-resource.ps1:10:1
Line |
  10 |  New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | 11:20:04 - The deployment 'DeployLocalTemplate' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s). Status Message: Provided combination of resource type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Deployment.MRP.Validators.DefaultResourceRequest and maintenance
     | Configuration scope InGuestPatch isn't supported. Resource: /subscriptions/f45372af-b935-4a3d-9ec3-2e4884fb186f/resourcegroups/infr-automation-weu-rg (Code:UnsupportedResourceOperation)  CorrelationId: 4d7eb050-1c10-45be-a462-eecd7e7b3774

DeploymentName          : DeployLocalTemplate
ResourceGroupName       : infr-automation-weu-rg
ProvisioningState       : Failed
Timestamp               : 23/01/2024 10:20:03
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            : 
Parameters              : 
                          Name                             Type                       Value
                          ===============================  =========================  ==========
                          maintenanceConfigurationsName    String                     "upd-group3-dtap-06am-pt-02-2024"
                          location                         String                     "westeurope"
                          rebootSetting                    String                     "Always"
                          resourceId                       String                     "994a56f5-8fd9-41cf-be99-204a5b54875d"
                          targetTag                        Object                     {"InSpark_ManagedUpdateGroup":"infr-upd-group2"}
                          subscription                     String                     "f45372af-b935-4a3d-9ec3-2e4884fb186f"

Outputs                 : 
DeploymentDebugLogLevel :
```

Comment: Can you please share your templates? as without scope the deployment takes endlesly

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to deploy it finally, letting scope and resourceId commented.

Pay attention to properties value, westeurope and not West Europe, microsoft.compute/virtualmachines and not Virtual Machine.